# Is there a way to define different site navigation and “Wiki Categories” column at the Sub site level instead of site collection level?

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, taxonomy

I have created a Site Collection and then I define sub sites under it. Now I created a term Store and I linked to the site collection navigation and Wiki Column.

But all the sub sites will get the same navigation and Wiki Categories as their parent site collection;

So my question is if there is a way to define the Site Navigation and Wiki Categories on the sub site level , so each sub site will have unique term store, navigation and Wiki Categories column?
Br

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i can modify the Sub Page Wiki Category column by accessing this column from the Library settings instead from the SubSite settings.

Comment: Just keep in mind that several Librarys can exist on the same sub web :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, under `/subsiteUrl/_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx` you can define that the subsite will use a different Global or Current Navigation and also specify a termset to use

Comment: thanks for your reply, it worked for the navigation, but what about the Wiki Categories colum is there a way to link it to a unique term store also?

Comment: Haven't really played around with Wiki categories, sorry

Comment: another question ,, why i have to type the URL myself to access the subsite navigation. is there a link from the site setting menu instead?

Comment: Yes the Navigation link under site settings (in the upper right column) takes you to the same spot, but the link was easier to provide ;)

Comment: i tried to access the subsite Colum by going to ""site setting--> site Columns"" but the "Wiki Categories " column is disabled unline when accessing it from the site collection level. so this might mean that i can not assign unique value to the Wiki Categories column or other column for a sub site ?? what do u think ?

Comment: Yes site columns are normally inherited from root web and down.

Comment: so in this way the Wiki Column for a SubSite should be the same as its parent site collection?